# Предупреждение при публикации приложения в Google Play "Unknown validation VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_ICON_NOT_UNIFORM"

Tags: android, google-play, публикация-приложений

При публикации приложения Google Play выскакивает предупреждение:

> Unknown validation VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_ICON_NOT_UNIFORM

В старой консоли это предупреждение не показывается, только в новой.

Не могу понять что означает предупреждение.

Кто знает?

Comment: Иконка приложения не стандартной формы(uniform). Как этого требуют новые правила.

Comment: @user28434 Об этом я и не подумал. До этого уже заметил что гугл округлил края иконок, не смотря на то, что по требованиям было квадратное изображение 512*512 пикселей. Есть какая-то информация чем грозит игнор данного сообщения? Может это только рекомендация или все же требование?

Comment: Пока только рекомендация. Но со временем будут закручивать гайки. И скоро не будут пускать.

Comment: Не  знаю почкму так, но предупреждение исчезло после того как перезалил ту же картинку что и стояла ранее.